# Possible error in call to routes.Redirect

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I am learning mvc3 the model views and controllers and now I am learning about routing in the global section, I came across [this tutorial](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/02/redirecting-routes-to-maintain-persistent-urls.aspx) which had map routes in this form.

```
var route = routes.MapRoute("new", "bar/{controller}/{id}/{action}");
routes.Redirect(r => r.MapRoute("old", "foo/{controller}/{action}/{id}"))
.To(route);
```

How can i duplicate that? The REDIRECT method is showing a red line underneath and it seems wrong.

Comment: What is the error when you mouseover the red line?

Comment: it says system.web.routing.routecollection does not contain a definition for Redirect

Comment: found the answer needed to get RouteMagic